# How to use Mongoose with GraphQL and DataLoader?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, mongoose, graphql

I am using **MongoDB** as my database and **GraphQL**. I am using **Mongoose** for my model. I realised my GraphQL queries are slow because the same documents are being loaded over and over again. I would like to use [**DataLoader**](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) to solve my problem, but I don't know how.

### Example

Let's say I have the following schema, describing users with friends :

```
// mongoose schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  friendIds: [String],
})

userSchema.methods.friends = function() {
  return User.where("_id").in(this.friendIds)
}

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

// GraphQL schema
const graphqlSchema = `
  type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    friends: [User]
  }

  type Query {
    users: [User]
  }
`

// GraphQL resolver
const resolver = {
  Query: {
    users: () => User.find()
  }
}
```

Here is some example data in my database :

```
[
  { id: 1, name: "Alice", friendIds: [2, 3] },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob", friendIds: [1, 3] },
  { id: 3, name: "Charlie", friendIds: [2, 4, 5] },
  { id: 4, name: "David", friendIds: [1, 5] },
  { id: 5, name: "Ethan", friendIds: [1, 4, 2] },
]
```

When I do the following GraphQL query :

```
{
  users {
    name
    friends {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

each user is loaded many times. I would like each user Mongoose document to be loaded only once.

### What doesn't work

#### Defining a "global" dataloader for fetching friends

If I change the `friends` method to :

```
// mongoose schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  friendIds: [String]
})

userSchema.methods.friends = function() {
  return userLoader.load(this.friendIds)
}

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

const userLoader = new Dataloader(userIds => {
  const users = await User.where("_id").in(userIds)
  const usersMap = new Map(users.map(user => [user.id, user]))
  return userIds.map(userId => usersMap.get(userId))
})
```

then my users are cached forever rather than on a per request basis.

#### Defining the dataloader in the resolver

[This seems more reasonable : one caching mechanism per request.](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader#creating-a-new-dataloader-per-request)

```
// GraphQL resolver
const resolver = {
  Query: {
    users: async () => {
      const userLoader = new Dataloader(userIds => {
        const users = await User.where("_id").in(userIds)
        const usersMap = new Map(users.map(user => [user.id, user]))
        return userIds.map(userId => usersMap.get(userId))
      })
      const userIds = await User.find().distinct("_id")
      return userLoader.load(userIds)
    }
  }
}
```

However, `userLoader` is now `undefined` in the `friends` method in Mongoose schema. Let's move the schema in the resolver then!

```
// GraphQL resolver
const resolver = {
  Query: {
    users: async () => {
      const userLoader = new Dataloader(userIds => {
        const users = await User.where("_id").in(userIds)
        const usersMap = new Map(users.map(user => [user.id, user]))
        return userIds.map(userId => usersMap.get(userId))
      })
      const userSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        friendIds: [String]
      })
      userSchema.methods.friends = function() {
        return userLoader.load(this.friendIds)
      }
      const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
      const userIds = await User.find().distinct("_id")
      return userLoader.load(userIds)
    }
  }
}
```

Mh ... Now Mongoose is complaining on the second request : resolver gets called again, and Mongoose doesn't like 2 models being defined with the same model name.

"Virtual populate" feature are of no use, because I can't even tell Mongoose to fetch models through the dataloader rather than through the database directly.

### Question

Has anyone had the same problem? Does anyone have a suggestion on how to use Mongoose and Dataloader in combination? Thanks.

*Note: I know since my schema is "relational", I should be using a relational database rather than MongoDB. I was not the one to make that choice. I have to live with it until we can migrate.*

Answer (score 8):

Keep your mongoose schema in a separate module. You don't want to create your schema each request -- just the first time the module is imported.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  friendIds: [String]
})
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

module.exports = { User }
```

If you want, you can also export a function that creates your loader in the same module. Note, however, that we do not want to export an instance of a loader, just a function that will return one.

```
// ...
const getUserLoader = () => new DataLoader((userIds) => {
  return User.find({ _id: { $in: userIds } }).execute()
})
module.exports = { User, getUserLoader }
```

Next, we want to include our loader in the context. How exactly this is done will depend on what library you're using to actually expose your graphql endpoint. In `apollo-server`, for example, context is passed in as part of your configuration.

```
new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => ({
        userLoader: getUserLoader()
    }),
})
```

This will ensure that we have a fresh instance of the loader created for each request. Now, your resolvers can just call the loader like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: async (root, args, { userLoader }) => {
      // Our loader can't get all users, so let's use the model directly here
      const allUsers = await User.find({})
      // then tell the loader about the users we found
      for (const user of allUsers) {
        userLoader.prime(user.id, user);
      }
      // and finally return the result
      return allUsers
    }
  },
  User: {
    friends: async (user, args, { userLoader }) => {
      return userLoader.loadMany(user.friendIds)
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't know you could add resolvers on a type the way you suggested for User. However, I also need the `friends` method elsewhere in my model : having it exposed only in GraphQL is not enough. It defeats the purpose of using an ORM.

Comment: You can still have the method. The larger point is that your model should not maintain a Dataloader instance. A new instance should be created per GraphQL request, per script execution, per whatever context your code is executing inside

Comment: That point was very clear to me, sorry if my question is not well asked. I could try to refine it. I tried making it simple. My real model is way more complex than the one presented here. I will have a deletedFriends method, an invitedFriends method, a closeFriends method ... each one refines the friends method by adding conditions to the query. Would you recommand having each method twice, once in my model, once in the GraphQL schema ? That seems very verbose / not DRY. I also want to use my model in a script execution, without GraphQL in front of it, and still benefit from DataLoader...